# HttpServletResonse sendRedirect - css not working

Tags: java, servlets, http-redirect

I want to redirect user to simple html page using HttpServletResponse response.

```
response.sendRedirect("/myPath/mySimplePage.html");
```

Html file looks like this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="customStyle.css">

</head>
<body>
   ...
</body>
</html>
```

customStyle.css file is in the same directory as my .html file. When I run it locally it works, but when I deploy the application on the server, .css is not included. What's the reason of such behavior?

Comment: Try `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./customStyle.css">` or  `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/customStyle.css">` . I'm not sure about the paths in Java.

Comment: @I.Manev
First version works locally, but does not work after deploy. I have a message in console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Second one does not work even locally.

Comment: Are you sure about that the file actually exists? Try Ctrl+F5 to refresh.

Comment: I am sure. As I said it works locally. I have tested it on different devices with the same result.

Comment: What about the file permissions ?

Comment: -rw-r--r-- the same as my .html file

Comment: From the chrome's developer options go to Sources->Network(sub-tab) and check if the file is present. If it's not, go to Network(tab) and check out where it tries to find the file.

Comment: It is present in 'Sources' but the file is empty. In Network I can see: Request URL: https://.../myPath/customStyle.css, which is a proper path to this file...

Comment: If the redirect points to `/mySimplePage.html` (an absolute path) the css should be available at `/customStyle.css`. Keep in mind how a redirect works. You'll get a response with a 3xx response code and a `location` header. Your client (your browser) will then try to load the given url from the location. The rendering of the HTML takes places afterwards. So loading http://hostname/mySimplePage.html should get the exact same result as loading the page which returns the redirect.

Comment: mySimplePage.html as well as cusotmStyle.css are in the same directory. Https://Hostname/myPath/...  I receive 404 not found for https://hostname/myPath/customStyle.css

Comment: But you are not redirecting to `myPath/mySimplePage.html` but to `/mySimplePage.html`. Try this: `response.sendRedirect("mySimplePage.html")`

Comment: Try to add relative path using `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` and check the url pattern in web.xml and leave it blank and then try it:

`<base href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">`

Answer (score 0):

From what was discussed in the comments the error seems to be that you redirect to an absolute path where the css you are referring to is not available. That means if your Servlet and your css are located at: `http://yourhost/myPath/redirectServlet` and `http://yourhost/myPath/customStyle.css` but you are redirect to `http://yourhost/mySimplePage.html` the css can't be accessed.

Long story short. The redirect does not change anything at all. If you can load the page `http://yourhost/mySimplePage.html` and the css is loaded you are fine.

---

How does a redirect works:

You send an HTTP-Request to a given URL (e.g. `http://yourhost/myPath/redirectServlet/`). The response you get contains a HTTP-Response code 302 (temporary redirect) and a HTTP-Location-Header. This header contains the URL or the path you provided (in your case "/mySimplePage.html"). The client will do another HTTP-Request using this location. In case of an URL it will send this Request to this URL. In case of a path it will use the same host as before using this path. If the path was relative the request will be send to inital URL + relative Path. If the path was absolute the request will go to the host + absolute Path.

Example:

Your redirect servlet is at `http://yourhost/anyPath/redirectServlet`

1. `response.sendRedirect("/mySimplePage.html");` will redirect you to `http://yourhost/mySimplePage.html`
2. `response.sendRedirect("mySimplePage.html");` will redirect you to `http://yourhost/anyPath/mySimplePage.html`
3. `response.sendRedirect("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48750057/httpservletresonse-sendredirect-css-not-working");` will redirect you to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48750057/httpservletresonse-sendredirect-css-not-working`

Hope that helps

Comment: I'm so sorry, but I've made a mistake in my question. I have  `response.sendRedirect(/myPath/mySimplePage.html)`. And once again, path for my css is `myPath/customStyle.css`, path for html is `myPath/mySimplePage.css`, so the directory is the same. When I do: `response.sendRedirect(/myPath/mySimplePage/html)` it works locally, but it does not work after deploy

Comment: OK. Just to stress this: Loading `http://yourhost/myPath/mySimplePage.html` works well while doing this using a redirect does not work?

Comment: please read my edited comment above. `http://localhost:8080/myPath/mySimplePage.html` works like a charm as well as redirect using localhost, but... `https://myhost/myPath/mySimplePage.html` does not load .css file. I got 404 not found. The page works, it opens, but without stylesheet.

Comment: So the problem is that the css is not available on the server. Can you give us some insides about how you upload your assets to the server?